# Stretch navigation bar to use available space

Tags: html, css

I am using the following html and using a min-width property to make sure my navbar doesn't go below a certain width, otherwise it will wrap under the image. You can verify this by manually decreasing the width of the browser window (see jsfiddle).

```
#pageHeader {    
    background-size: cover;
    min-width: 550px;
}

<div id="pageHeader">
    <img class="myLogo" id="logo" src="http://www.growingvoters.org/images/online-voting-tools.jpg">    

    <div class="mainMenu" id="mainMenu">
        <a class="navLink menuItem" href="#">DASHBOARD</a>
        <a class="navLink menuItem" href="#">NEWS</a>
        <a class="navLink menuItem" href="#">CONTACT</a>
        <a class="navLink menuItem" href="#">ABOUT</a>
        <a class="navLink menuItem" href="#">CAREERS</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mmn24kab/

But is there any way of coaxing the navbar to use as much horizontal real estate as is available when the screen is at full width. I feel this should be simple but just can't seem to figure it out.
I did try and find similar questions but had no luck.

Comment: Do you mean have the links fill the rest of the page? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/ftLhrp9c/).... Or use positioning: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/ftLhrp9c/1/)

Comment: @jbutler483 Yes, I think your second post above is closest to what I'm looking for as it preserves the fact that the menu items do not eventually wrap when the browser width is decreased. But is the "calc" expression supported in FF?

Comment: [Yes, it's supported without prefixing](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). Only unless you need FF 15> support, where you might want to include a -moz- prefix.  As for 'old' webkit browsers, you would be safer to add a webkit prefix. (Chrome 25>)

Answer (score 0):

How's [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mmn24kab/1/)?:

```
.mainMenu {
    height: 30px;
    padding-top: 55px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
}
.myLogo{
    width:80px;
    height:80px;    
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, when at full screen (width) the navigation bar is still predominately over to the right and does not stretch to fill the space between itself and the logo.

Comment: So you want the menu items to spread out? The above makes the menu bar's width fill. See the link that @jbutler483 just posted if you want the items to spread.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @media (min-width: 700px) {
.mainMenu {
    width: 85%;
}


.menuItem {
    margin: 0 2%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }
}
```

I put this at the bottom of your CSS in the fiddle. It's a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) that  converts to percentages after a certain width.

Comment: Had thought of media queries but unfortunately the point at which the new style is applied kind of happens abruptly. I was hoping to get a smooth, dynamic transition as you change the width of the screen.